# Simple structure with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, struct

Right after scanning the second element, the program crashes. It is not able to go to the scanning of the third element(i.e. grade). Need help, in figuring out what I am wrong wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define NUM 2
typedef struct STUDENT
{
    int ID;
    char *name;
    char *grade;
};
int main ()
{
        int i;
    struct STUDENT *s;
    s = (struct STUDENT*)malloc(NUM*sizeof(struct STUDENT*));
    printf("Enter Student's ID, Name and Grade:\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter ID:\n");
        scanf("%d", &(s+i)->ID);
        printf("Enter Student Name:\n");
        scanf("%s", (s+i)->name);
        printf("Enter Grade:\n");
        scanf("%s", (s+i)->grade);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nInformation of the student's are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    {
        printf("Student ID = %d\n", (s+i)->ID);
        printf("Student Name = %s\n", &(s+i)->name);
        printf("Student grade = %c\n", &(s+i)->grade);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not allocate memory for `grade` and `name` in `struct STUDENT`. Trying to read input and write it to them produces undefined behavior.

Add the necessary `malloc`s, for example with a given maximum length `STR_MAX`:

```
s[i].name = malloc(STR_MAX);
s[i].grade = malloc(STR_MAX);
```

See the other answers for further errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
malloc(NUM*sizeof(struct STUDENT*));
```

should be

```
malloc(NUM*sizeof(struct STUDENT));
```

also, the `name` and `grade` are not buffers but pointers. You may need a buffer (char array) or allocate memory for it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

1. `struct STUDENT *s;` should be declared like this:

   ```
   STUDENT *s;
   ```
2. No need to cast `void *` from `malloc`.  Change this line `s = (struct STUDENT*)malloc(NUM*sizeof(struct STUDENT*));` to this:

   ```
   s = malloc(NUM * sizeof(*s));
   ```
3. Instead of this `scanf("%d", &(s+i)->ID);`, the following may be easier to understand:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &s[i].ID);
   ```
4. Same here:

   ```
   printf("Student ID = %d\n", s[i].ID);
   ```
5. Most importantly, what Nabla said.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct STUDENT
{
    int ID;
    char *name;
    char *grade;
};
```

Here name and grade character type pointer. so when you malloc structure you also have to malloc name and grade too